# How to Separate Mesh by "Loose Parts" through Python API?

Tags: python, mesh

I would like to automate the process of modifying a .fbx file but I'm not quite sure why my code isn't working. All I'm doing is importing a .fbx file, separating the mesh by "Loose Parts", and then exporting it back out. Any thoughts?

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath="C:/Users/'user'/Downloads/Futuristic_ghetto_building/Futuristic ghetto building_one_Mesh_fbx.fbx")
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

buildings = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
buildings.select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
```

Note: The code isn't exporting anything right now for testing purposes

Comment: You want to separate `objects['Plane']` only? Did the imported fbx named 'Plane'? And are you use version 2.79 and below?

Comment: Yes I would like to separate the “Plane” mesh as it shows in the objects tab. The fbx file itself is not named planes but the house mesh imported into the scene is called “Plane”. I’m using version 2.83

Comment: If you're using newer Blender (2.80 and above) I don't think `buildings.select = True` will be able to run. You should use `buildings.select_set(True)` instead